# How to treat cp -r always as directory?

Tags: cp

I have to copy some files and I have a field where I write the destination path. But if I do not write "/" at the end, it takes the last word and creates a file with that name.  How can treat everything as directory?

Example :

```
/home/folder1/folder2
```

In that way, it creates file with name `folder2` in directory `folder1`.

Comment: Try adding a `/` at the end of the name.

Comment: Yes, but if the user do not write at the end it should treat it also as directory. How to implement that ? 

cp -r ${Path1} ${Path2}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cp -r -t target inputs
```

Will ensure that target shall be taken to be as a directory. GNU cp is needed.

Comment: I did not find any command that can fix my problem, so i use this : 

if [ ! -d {$Path} ]; then
     mkdir -p ${PATH}
 fi